# Proving $n^{n+r}>(n+r)^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

> Proving $n^{n+r}>(n+r)^n$ for $n,r>2$, both natural numbers

I know that $n^{n+1}>(n+1)^n$, so if I only increase $''n+1''$ part by $1$, the inequality is still true, i.e. $n^{n+2}>(n+2)^n$ because the ratio of the left side is $n$ and the right side is $(1+\frac1{n+1})^n<e$, so iterating in this way I can reach $n+r$, do you agree ?

Comment: Try writing $n^{n+r} = ((n+r) - r)^{n+r}$ on the left side and apply Binomial expansion.

Comment: $r \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Your argument is not convincing at all.

Comment: @Dominik Is it not valid ? or does it not look well ?

Comment: Now how did you prove that $(1+\frac1{n+1})^n<e$ for all $n>2$?

Comment: @beretta It is difficult to understand what you mean exactly, this is why it is not convincing. I guess that the argument is simply invalid, even if you were to write it down more rigorously.

Comment: @SimpleArt Well $(1+\frac1{n+1})^n\le(1+\frac1{n+1})^{n+1}<e$

Comment: @Dominik perhaps you would care to fix the argument, and give some criticism? your comment wasn't helpful, and their argument was clearly meant to be heuristic in the first place.

Comment: @TheCount The question was whether this argument is valid - and I answered that it is not. There is not a simply fixable mistake in the proof, there is just no argument to be found.

Comment: @Dominik So, if you took an exam and that was the question, you would just write that it was wrong, and provide no justification? You didn't help the OP.

Comment: @TheCount What else is there to write? There *is no point* where I could say "Here is your mistake, you could fix it in this way ...". There is simply no argument in OPs post. If you think there is a way to write such an answer, then feel free to write it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something similar.

We want to show $n^r< (1+\frac{r}{n})^n$.

Now notice that $e^r=1+r+\frac{r^2}{2!}+\dots $

Using binomial expansion one can easily conclude that $ (1+\frac{r}{n})^n< e^r< n^r$ (because $\dfrac{\binom{n}{j}}{n^j}< \frac{1}{j!})$

Answer (score 3):

Taking logarithms on both sides, the inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{\ln(n + r)}{n + r} < \frac{\ln(n)}{n}.$$

Now consider the function $x \mapsto \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$. The derivative is $\frac{1 - \ln(x)}{x^2}$, which is negative for $x > e$. But this means that the function is decreasing in this range, which proves the original inequality.

Answer (score 2):

$n^{n+r}\gt(n+r)^n$

$n^{n+r\over n }\gt(n+r)$

$n^{1\over n}\gt (n+r)^{1\over n+r}$

$^{n}\sqrt{n} \gt $ $^{n+r}\sqrt{n+r}$

we know that $^{x}\sqrt{x}$ is Descending after $e$
so if we increase x decrease value of function

and we have $f'(x)=x^{{1\over x}-2}(ln x -1)$ so for x>2 derivative is negative and function is Descending

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put $n+r=m$ and prove that

$n^m>m^n$ if $m\geq n+3$.

or $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}-\frac{\ln(m)}{m}>0$.

the derivative of the function $f: x\mapsto \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ has the sign of the numerator $(1-\ln(x))$ so,
$f$ is decreasing at $[3,+\infty)$, and
$$\forall m>n>2 \;\;\frac{\ln(m)}{m}<\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$ qed.